# XCode workspaces and subprojects

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got an XCode project that I'd like to break down into subprojects if possible.

Each subapp is large enough that it is much easier to develop it independently and then incorporate it into the main app. However this is proving annoying having to copy everything over and fix linking issues.

I've begun looking into workspaces (which I already have from cocoapods) and static libraries.
Workspaces like it might be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to link the subprojects together so I can run the main app and it compiles and builds the subapps into it....

I'm not sure if static libraries is what I want; just by the term, it seems like it might be more of a utility-type.

Anybody have any experience with this??

Comment: Your question is "anybody has any experience"? That's pretty hard to answer.

Comment: However, to put it simply, create a new workspace and drag & drop the xcodeproject files from the finder into the workspace. If you need a subproject dependency, drag the project into another project (the project can appear several times in the workspace). Depending on the structure (static libraries? dynamic libraries?) you will have to add some build steps (copy headers) or linking steps.

Comment: "much easier to develop it independently" - I would create different branches and develop them independently,once done merge back to trunk. I always keep the branches up to date to reduce work on merge. This way it is easier. Sorry, it doesn't answer your question directly.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm a little new to asking questions here....